# How to synchronize remote database with local database in MongoDB and nodejs?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, angular, ionic2

I am new for MongoDB and Nodejs.

I have created my Nodejs server and MongoDB database on Amazon instance.

Now, I want to create a native mobile app with Ionic and Angular-4. 
I Need the Mobile app to work offline. So, need synchronize remote database with a local database that is created in MongoDB.

So, question is that it is possible in synchronizing remote database with local database in MongoDB? 
And it possible to use MongoDB as a local database for Android Mobile app which created with Ionic and Angular-4?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB can not work as local storage. There is a very good and recent article [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-summary-of-local-storage-options-for-phonegap-applications/) that list the possible solutions you have today.